# Can I generate AWS S3 Policy Strings Automatically for New Buckets?

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to create an S3 bucket in test, make it a website, and make all objects in it visible.  The AWS Policy Generator will take a bucket name, and wants an object name.  Can I glob it as `bucket/*`?  Also, the resulting policy JSON contains an ID.  Since I may not know the bucket name, does it mean I have to pregenerate policies for all possible buckets?  Or is this ID only a unique reference and can be also generated along with the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

#### Objec Name Wildcard

> Can I glob it as bucket/*?

Yes - while the related documentation in [Specifying Amazon S3 Resources in Bucket Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingResOpsConditions.html) irritatingly only states *the format for the resource’s name is bucketname/keyname, where bucketname is the name of the bucket and keyname is the full name of the object* and doesn't mention the wildcard (*) option, wildcards are used in the [Example Cases for Amazon S3 Bucket Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html) and also confirmed in [Special Information for Amazon S3 Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_SpecialInfo.html):

> The value for Resource must be prefixed with the bucket name or the
>   bucket name and a path under it (bucket/*). If only the bucket name is
>   specified, without the trailing /*, the policy applies to the bucket.

#### Policy ID

> - Since I may not know the bucket name, does it mean I have to
>     pregenerate policies for all possible buckets? Or is this ID only a
>     unique reference and can be also generated along with the JSON?

While both *Id* and *Sid* are *an optional identifier* within the [Access Policy Language](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage.html) as such, you indeed need to specify unique IDs within Amazon S3 policies in particular, see [Special Information for Amazon S3 Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_SpecialInfo.html) again:

> - Each policy must have a unique policy ID (Id)
> - Each statement in a policy must have a unique statement ID (sid)

However, you can generate that unique ID yourself along with the JSON - as usual it is recommended to *use a UUID for the value, or incorporate a UUID as part of the ID to ensure uniqueness*.